# laravel controller doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

1. I'm following [CodeHappy: Using Controllers](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/using-controllers) to learn to use laravel controllers, in my PC *"myproject/"* points to *"wamp/www/laravel/public"* folder, when I try *"myproject/account/login"* the browser shows:

---

## Not Found

The requested URL /account/login was not found on this server.

---

2. Obviously, the browser tries to find the "account" folder instead of using controller, I created the "account" folder under "public" and tried again, my guess was proved right. Should I config anywhere before using controllers?

#### My code:

application/controllers/account.php

```
<?php
class Account_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function action_index(){
        echo "This is the profile page.";
    }
    public function action_login(){
        echo "This is the login form.";
    }
    public function action_logout(){
        echo "This is the logout action.";
    }
}
```

/application/routes.php

```
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('home.index');
    });
    Route::controller('account');
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with controllers?  Have you confirmed that plain routes work, like Route::get('my/something', function() { return 'world'; }); Perhaps try visiting http://myproject/index.php/account/login - this will confirm whether your rewriting rules are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phill Sparks has it completely right (rightfully so! He's been using Laravel for ages). If your browser is reporting a 404 from the **server**, unless you completely removed the 404 event, then the request did not even go through Laravel.

Try `/index.php/account/login`. If it works, you know that your rewrite rules are botched. If it doesn't work either, then you have a much more serious issue at hand.

If you are using Apache, you should find in your `htaccess` file the rewrite rules for Laravel. If you cannot load mod_rewrite through htaccess, you'll need to migrate them to your server config.

If you are using nginx, you will need something similar to this in your `server` block:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;
    }
    location @laravelDesktop {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```

Or if in a subdirectory

```
    location /my/subdir/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;
    }
    location @laravel {
            rewrite ^/my/subdir/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```